# Вывести определенную информацию в textarea

Tags: javascript, html

При выборе определенного чекбокса в поле `textarea` должна вписываться определенная информация. Допустим я выбрал базовую комплектацию + коврики + диски.

В поле с тестом должно вписываться каждый их выбранных элементов и его цена. Потом все цены должны суммироваться и выдавать полную стоимость выбранного комплекта.

Помогите или подскажите как правильно это можно реализовать.

```js
function check() {
  var base = document.getElementById('base');
  var mat = document.getElementById('mat');
  var crank = document.getElementById('crank');
  var tires = document.getElementById('tires');
  var disks = document.getElementById('disks');

  var arr = ['ffff'
    base, mat, crank, tires, disks
  ];
  var newArr = arr.filter(callback);

  var baseValue = 2000000;
  var matValue = 3000;
  var crankValue = 5000;
  var tiresValue = 20000;
  var disksValue = 5000;

}

function callback(arr) {
  return arr.checked == true;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form name="carshop">
    <h2>Комплектация автомобиля</h2>

    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="checkboxes">
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="base" value="2000000" checked disabled>Базовая комплектация</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="mat" value="3000">Коврики</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="crank" value="5000">Защита картера</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="tires" value="20000">Зимние шины</label>
        <label><input type="checkbox" id="disks" value="5000">Литые диски</label>
      </div>
      <div class="image"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="calculation">
      <label>Цена:<textarea id="text"></textarea></label>
    </div>
    <div class="buttons">
      <input class="button" type="button" value="Рассчитать" onclick="check()">
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function check() {
  var text = "";
  var value = 0;

  var options = document.querySelectorAll('.wrapper .checkboxes label');
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var check = options[i].querySelector("input");
    if (check.checked) {
      value += +check.value;
      text += options[i].innerText + " - " + check.value + "\n";
    }
  }

  var memo = document.getElementById('text');
  memo.value = text + "\n" + "Total - " + value;
}
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="checkboxes">
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="base" value="2000000" checked disabled>Базовая комплектация</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="mat" value="3000">Коврики</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="crank" value="5000">Защита картера</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="tires" value="20000">Зимние шины</label><br>
    <label><input type="checkbox" id="disks" value="5000">Литые диски</label>
  </div>
  <div class="image"></div>
</div>

<div class="calculation">
  <label>Цена:<textarea id="text"></textarea></label>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <input class="button" type="button" value="Рассчитать" onclick="check()">
</div>
```

Comment: Код работает, огромное спасибо. Правда я не совсем понял как

Comment: @Juzo Пожалуйста. Читайте про функции, которые Вам неизвестны, и спрашивайте, что непонятно. Успехов!